# Best practice for sectioning

Tags: sectioning

So I've been using latex for a while. I've been only using it for homework.
What I usually do to create sections for different problem is using

```
\section*{Ex 1:}

\subsection*{Solution:}

*solution*
```

Is this the best practice? I could for example use an `enumerate` environment, or maybe something else I'm not aware of.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use packages especially designed for exercises sheets, like `exsheets` for example.

Comment: What to  do depends a lot on the expected output. Are all your exercises numbered consecutively? Do you want each exercise to start on a new page? ...

Answer (score 1):

Personally for me, I try to avoid colons in titles (which somehow look weird), especially at the end of a title. The colon doesn't add anything meaningfull to your section title, you could go as well without them.

Instead of using `\subsection*{Solution}`, have you thought about using theorem-like environments? The [`amsthm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package is a popular one (others include [`ntheorem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) and [`mdframed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed)). You could define in your preamble

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution} % No numbering
%\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}[section] % Numbering with <sec.no>.<sol.no>

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}[by induction] % Optional parameter in parentheses
    <your solution>
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

`amsmath` is very robust, but in that sense a bit limited. `ntheorem` and `mdframed` have much more features, but also have their limitations. So every package has it's pros and cons.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of theorem-like environment since I'm still pretty new to latex in general. I'll check it out thanks.

Comment: An additional bonus: if you want to combine your homework solutions into one giant PDF, you can separate them by sections.